# MapView Camera not changing in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, subview, gmsmapview

I would appreciate some help for my problem, I am creating a view called mapView and have changed its class to GMSMapView.
But when I assign the map to this mapView, the layout is perfectly fine but the camera is set to Europe by default, which does not change.

Following is the code:

```
 @IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!
var latitudes = [19.199782,19.19855,19.199179]
var longitudes = [72.8734634,72.872935, 72.874535]
var titles = ["Riviera","Alica","Senate"]
var subTitle = ["1","2","3"]
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 19.20060, longitude: 72.8734462, zoom: 15.0)
    let mapView1 = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)


    let path = GMSMutablePath()


    for i in 0...2
    {
        let marker = GMSMarker()
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitudes[i], longitude: longitudes[i])
        marker.title = titles[i]

        marker.snippet = subTitle[i]
        marker.map = mapView1
        path.add(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitudes[i], longitude: longitudes[i]))
    }

    let polyLine = GMSPolyline(path: path)

    polyLine.map = mapView1


    mapView = mapView1
    mapView.camera = camera

}
```

The output for the code is:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mL3J.png)

When I add the map to view I get the desired map

modification to above code:
instead of mapView = mapView1 put 
view = mapView1

Desired output:[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kiqte.png)

So please help me getting the desired output in the mapView view of my screen.
Thank You!

Comment: Why have you created the new variable mapView1? You can assign directly the properties to your mapView.

Comment: DionizB , I tried your way but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

The GMSMapView class has the following function:

```
animate(to:GMSCameraPosition)
```

So in your code, instead of setting the camera property on your mapview, do this:

```
mapView.animate(to: camera)
```

Hope this helps!

### Edit

After looking more into this code, I believe your mapView1 is unnecessary and causing problems with your outlet. Try something like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 19.20060, longitude: 72.8734462, zoom: 15.0)
    let path = GMSMutablePath()

    for i in 0...2
    {
        let marker = GMSMarker()
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitudes[i], longitude: longitudes[i])
        marker.title = titles[i]

        marker.snippet = subTitle[i]
        marker.map = mapView
        path.add(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitudes[i], longitude: longitudes[i]))
    }

    let polyLine = GMSPolyline(path: path)
    polyLine.strokeWidth = 2.0
    polyLine.strokeColor = .black
    polyLine.map = mapView

    mapView.animate(to: camera)
}
```

On a side note I would also suggest replacing your four arrays with one array of dictionary objects each containing a title, subtitle, latitude and longitude, or something like that. Then change your for loop to accommodate

Comment: @NewCoder Edited my original post

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest setting view's class to UIView, since you create the mapView1 programmatically and then after initializing mapView1

`let mapView1 = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)`

add it to the view as `addSubview(mapView1)`.

Hope this helps you!